# Typescript/Intellisesnse (wrongly?) picking up variable from another file (lib.dom.d.ts)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Today I referenced an unnamed/undefined variable but Typescript/Intellisense did not catch it, leading to a bug in my code. The variable name is "status", and Intellisense picked up the definition from the file `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`. (I am using Linux Ubuntu 20.04)

More details:

I initialized a basic project to demonstrate the error (Sorry I can't seem to post images because reputation is low)

[unamed "status" variable does not create error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4Zp.png)

Upon clicking "Find all references", I found "status" has been declared in a random lib.dom.d.ts file

["status" has been declared in a random lib.dom.d.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrA3u.png)

This seems to have been because I install Typescript globally? I also installed Typescript in the project; both installations are up-to-date with version "typescript@4.3.4"

I also checked if this is only a VSCode-specific bug, but Sublime Text's LSP-typescript also picked up the same wrong definition.

How do I solve this issue ?

My tsconfig.json is as followed

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exlude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type definition is correct.

It's [defined by `window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) (although deprecated), so `status` should be considered a global in the browser context.

I ran into the same issue yesterday with `close`/`window.close`.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. I hope the Typescript doc have another section for confusing variable names like this.

So how do I instruct Typescript to not include the browser context into my API files ?

Comment: Okay I have found the way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @spender's answer, I realized that this is the expected behavior of Typescript, and it is me who have wronged.

I solved the issue by adding a ["lib" option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) into my tsconfig.json. It seems that if I exclude the "lib" option, Typescript will default include all libs. But I don't want the "dom" lib to interfere with my backend code, so I use: `"lib": ["es2015"]`

If I ever use the "dom" lib in the future, I guess I will just have to be extra careful